# QandA program loop A if answered incorrectly

Tags: java, joptionpane

im currently building a question and  answer program. but im stuck since i want to repeat the question (unlimited if the user still wants to continue answering the question until she/he quits the game.) you cant move to the next until answered correctly. please help me =.=

```
    String twoanswer = "Stamp";
    String tworesponse = "";
        tworesponse = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("It goes all over the world, but always stays in a corner. What is that?\nhint:_ _ _ _ _");
        if (tworesponse.equalsIgnoreCase(twoanswer))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are correct!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Question Number: 3");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are wrong.");
            int reply1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Want to try again?", "Try again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (reply1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer again!");
                    //repeat to tworesponse ( the question)
                }
                if (reply1 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                {
                    int reply1dot1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", "Quit game?", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
                        if (reply1dot1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for playing!");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        if (reply1dot1 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                        {
                            int reply1dot2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Try again?", "Try again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                            if (reply1dot2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer again!");
                                //return to tworesponse question
                            }
                            if (reply1dot2 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for playing!");
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: I want to loop again from the start/question. see the comments that return to the question. I confirm him/her to try again if she/he wants to try again to answer, so if she/he said yes. the question will be showed again. until answered correctly or she/he stop the game.

Comment: I will give you a pseudo code.

Comment: thank you. note that this is question number 2 already. i cant to the do while since it doesnt continue to question 3 after answered correctly =.=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of pseudo code you can change it to java code:

```
for(Question question: questions){
    Answer answer = askQuestion(Question)

    if(question.answer = answer)
        showInfo("you are correct, next question will be " + question.num + 1)
    else{
        response = showInfo("you are wrong. do you want to try?")

        if(response = no)
            break;
    }

}
Answer askQuestion(Question question){

    return showQuestion(question);

}
```

Comment: do i need to change main method here?